# How to introduce myself?

Tags: writing

"U" is a Burmese equivalent of "Mr".

> I am Mr. Thant.
>       I am U Thant.
>      I am Thant.

I'd like to know which is correct?

Comment: I don't know Burmese. But I think all are correct. It's a matter of taste, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, user178049. Burmese means Myanmar, a country in Southeast Asia.

Comment: I think what @user178049 means is that he doesn't know how to speak Burmese, but I'm sure he know what Burmese means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about learning English.

Comment: This question is about learning English, specifically about conventions for carrying a foreign term of address into English. It's a good question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would say

> My name is U Thant.
>   I am U Thant.

the **U** is an honorific title as in the former Secretary General of the UN

> [U Thant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_Thant)

but his name is

> **Pantanaw** U Thant, in reference to his hometown, Pantanaw